# Can I send only patient demographic information to PACS system using objective C?

Tags: objective-c, dicom

While working on the DICOM I am successful to send the images and videos.

Below is the code to send Images to PACS

```
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"jpeg"] )
    {
        TransferSyntaxes.push_back(UID_JPEGProcess1TransferSyntax);
        if (dicomSCU) {
            dicomSCU->addPresentationContext(UID_VLMicroscopicImageStorage, TransferSyntaxes);
            result = dicomSCU->initNetwork();
            result = dicomSCU->negotiateAssociation();
        }
```

Can I send only the demographic information such as Name, Sex, DOB, to PACS?

what should be the transfer syntax or any code base to refer?

Comment: My requirement is quite simple I tried sending PDF which works with the  TransferSyntaxes.push_back(UID_SPM2PDFrameOfReference); , However I am not quite sure how exactly the DICOM expects to send the demographic patient data  only @AmitJoshi

Comment: Guys, I think that the question need more clarity or the whole discussion is going totally wrong here. If you want to just "create a patient" in the PACS but do not store any DICOM object, then there is no DICOM way to do that. What you send to PACS *must* conform to an SOP Class / Information Object definition. The Detached Patient Management has been retired many years ago. HL7 ADT is used to "announce" patients  for a PACS in the IHE Scheduled Workflow.

Comment: @kritzel_sw, to be more specific, when I send an image I send the patient details along with that and it creates the patient in my PACS server,  Which means the patient creation is possible if I send an image, Now the question is can I send only the patient data, without the image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no DICOM way to do this. There had been a DICOM Service Class called "Detached Patient Management" but this has been retired very many years ago.

The problem of sending an image without image data is that there is no DICOM SOP Class that allows you to create a valid object of that. One possible solution would be sending a non-image SOP Class, e.g. an Encapsulated PDF or a Basic Text SR. Still these objects need some "body" (the PDF or a plain text). It is questionable if PACS users would love such a dummy object just for the creation of a patient.

The "official" way of "announcing" a patient to the PACS is based on HL7 ADT messages or on FHIR. Unfortunately it is not guaranteed that all PACS products you will encounter in the field have implemented such a service. Even in the [IHE Technical Framework](https://www.ihe.net/ihe_domains/radiology/) there is no way to send an ADT for patient registration to the PACS ("Image Manager in IHE terminology" , see RAD-1). However there is a way to announce a procedure (RAD-4, HL7 ORM) at the image manager which will create a patient without any images. But that does not only create a patient but also a procedure for which it is expected that images are subsequently transferred.